# smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server. Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to run a python script to automate sending emails but I keep running into this error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
 import smtplib
 from email import message


 from_addr = 'myemail@gmail.com'
 to_addr = 'myemail@gmail.com'
 subject = 'Test Email'
 body = 'Test'
 msg = message.Message()
 msg.add_header('from', from_addr)
 msg.add_header('to', to_addr)
 msg.add_header('subject', subject)
 msg.set_payload(body)
 server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 server.login(from_addr, 'password')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program `Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 716, in login`
    raise SMTPNotSupportedError(

  smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) to login your account via `smtp`. This solves the issue for less secure app feature.

Coming towards your error it might be due to something is not supported but here I see you have not started **TLS** connection. Starting **TLS** connection can solve this error if there's no other issue.

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_addr, 'password') # here you can need to use app password
```

This should solve the error most of the time if other things are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure, but for gmail you need https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps Allow less secure apps: ON setting.

Or you need Google APIs for authentication: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  Google recent ended support for "allow less secure apps" and the commonly recommended answer of using an app password also does not appear to work reliably either (it will work sometimes, but then gmail will start rejecting the authentication a day or two later).

Google's suggested quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) is incomplete but does eventually work.  In that process, you will get an error because you did not redirect the URI.  You'll need to add this to the approved URIs within your google API console and then follow the link again.

You will hit a 2nd issue because your user will not be approved to use your own project.  You will need to add your gmail account as a test user.

Once you have the URI forwarding correctly and you are approved to use your own app, you will then get an error (HTTP Error 403) because the Gmail API will not be activated.  Go back to the google API console and enable the Gmail API.  Finally, you can run the quickstart.py file again and it will complete without errors.

I have not yet tested this solution for actually sending email, but it does appear to grant your app full access to the email account that you set up.  I also do not know if this is a long term solution or if there are tokens which will time out.

Based on the difficulty of this, it seems that finding another email SMTP service may be a better solution if that's possible for your situation.