# How do I use SMTP with Gmail after the Update?

Tags: python, email, automation, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to automate sending Emails with STMP and after researching a bit, [Access to your Google Account from less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?visit_id=637897600972830021-1208650744&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1)

> "The Answer from Google Support") if I'm using Gmail it doesn't work anymore just with Email and Password.

so this code:

```
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
```

does not work anymore. Does anybody know how to do it so it works again?
Or an alternative Email Company that doesn't have this "Feature"?

Comment: I was having a similar issue and have written my potential solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653908/8341691

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending and email using python - Problem causes by last Google policy update (on less secure apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478573/sending-and-email-using-python-problem-causes-by-last-google-policy-update-on)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using gmail through python without smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623017/using-gmail-through-python-without-smtp)

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to use login and password but you can use [Xoauth](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) in order to access the smtp server.

If you have a google workspace account you could also use gmail api using a service account with domain wide delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You must create App password. Going to [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/). Security tab. After active 2 Step Verification, new option under "Signing in to Google" the "App passwords" option will be actived. Just create one app password and use as password to authenticate

Comment: Have you tested that this works?  The point of this change is that google doesnt want us using login and password to access users accounts.   the better option is to use Xoauth2

Comment: @DaImTo I've tested and it works. No need to change old system, just generate a App Password, replace with old mail password. Simple and easy to use.