# How to send an email using python after Google's policy update on not allowing just username and password?

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to learn how to send an email using python. All the tutorials on the web that I have read explain how to do it using Gmail.

But, from 30/05/2022 (despite the fact that everybody is free to do whatever he wants with his account) Google has a new policy that states:

> To help keep your account secure, starting May 30, 2022, Google will no longer support the use of third-party apps or devices that only ask for your username and password for you. Sign in to your Google account.

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

And we get:
[image]

So my question is there any other way to send an email using python, (including email accounts belonging to an other company)?

Here is my function to send an email:

```
def send_email_fct(filename, filepath, fromaddr, mdpfrom, toaddr):
"""" filename: file name to be sent with extension
     filepath: file path of the file to be sent
     fromaddr: sender email address
     mdpfrom: password of sender email address
     toaddr: receiver email address"""

msg = MIMEMultipart()  # instance of MIMEMultipart
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "data file"

body_email = "Body_of_the_mail"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body_email, 'plain'))

attachment = open(filepath, 'rb')  # open the file to be sent

p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')  # instance of MIMEBase
p.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(p)
p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(p)  # attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg'

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  # SMTP
s.starttls()
s.login(fromaddr, mdpfrom)

text = msg.as_string()

s.sendmail(from_email_addr, toaddr, text)  # sending the email

s.quit()  # terminating the session
```

And I get this error:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c12-20020aa7d60c000000b0042be14040c1sm2612116edr.86 - gsmtp')
```

To fix this problem, I think that the only line that need to be change is this one:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

If you know by what I can change it or if you see any other error, it will help me a lot! :-)

Comment: You need to generate an "App Password" in the sender's Google account. Then use that password in s.login(). It would work. I just tried it. That said, my email ended up as spam in recipient's inbox. Don't know why.

Comment: @Firelord Thk a lor for your answe. Can you be more precise? how i generate " generate an "App Password""? Or better post the edited code (from mine) that works as answer?

Comment: See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en // I didn't use your code sample. I used a bare bone code sample to test if a successful email can be sent using smtplib with Google's SMTP server. it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email with python. Google disables less secure apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480454/sending-email-with-python-google-disables-less-secure-apps)

Comment: small typo: the s.sendmail(...) uses an undefined from_email_addr that should simply be fromaddr.
Thanks a lot for this! It solved my day with some 209 emails to post with attach!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a more precise answer with all the main steps. I hope it will help other people.

1. Log in into your email account: https://myaccount.google.com
2. Then go to the security part

[image]

Be sure that you have turn on two steps verification and click on "App password." As of 9th July 2023, this might not be visible, but is reachable directly via [myaccount.google.com/apppasswords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)

[image]

3. After select email and the corresponding device

[image]

4. It will generate a password that will look like this; it is this password that you have to use in your python script.

[image]

5. This password will appear here; in this place, you will have the option to erase it (so it will be no longer be useful to connect to your email account).

[image]

Hope it will help other people!

Comment: @Marco With pleasure :-) me too i was really stuck when i encountered this proble (i am a noob in prog)

Comment: vrey big help thank you!

Comment: You really could have accepted the answer by [Gustavo Pinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6718046/gustavo-pinto) instead of adding your own since it contained all the info needed and you actually made use of it yourself. The added screenshots are only so useful because web GUIs of popular services are pretty ephemeral.

Answer (score 18):

Solved it by creating an **App password**.

1. You have to go to [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
2. In the [Security tab](https://myaccount.google.com/security), activate 2 Step Verification
3. After this a new option under "Signing in to Google" called "[App passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)" should be be active
4. Just create an app password and use that as the password to authenticate

Comment: Have you tested that this works?  The point of this change is that google doesnt want us using login and password to access users accounts.   the better option is to use Xoauth2

Comment: work for me to send simple messages but not if i want to send an attached file

Comment: @Dalmto It is working when i m not trying to send an attached file (.txt). btw what is Xoauth2?