# SMTP email error after Google's removal of less secure app access

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

**Error:**

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/signup/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n1-20020a05620a294100b006a6b6638a59sm3664075qkp.53 - gsmtp')
```

Before the update, the email sender works. Now after the update the email sender has a STMP authentication error.

How can I fix this error?

**Code:**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'tonoabot.noreply@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['mailbotPass']
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email with python. Google disables less secure apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480454/sending-email-with-python-google-disables-less-secure-apps)

Comment: @Firelord It dosnt display the error anymore, but still doesn't send email!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into generating an [app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB). The password generated can then be used in the place of the the actual password for that account.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'tonoabot.noreply@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['appsPassword']
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: I had same problem recently, this answer should solve it.