# Failed to send mail with smtplib: "TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed"

Tags: python, smtplib

This is the code part

```
from smtplib import SMTP

my_mail = "tt5938614@gmail.com"
my_password = "iqftddpnopuqnuii"

connection = SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_mail, password=my_password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_mail, to_addrs="hema182009@yahoo.com", msg="Subject:Hello\n\nWelcome everyone.")
connection.close()
```

I get the following

```
File "C:\Users\badra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
  raise exceptions[0]
File "C:\Users\badra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
  sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email using python after Google's policy update on not allowing just username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478573/how-to-send-an-email-using-python-after-googles-policy-update-on-not-allowing-j)