# Email without error but not send the massage

Tags: python, email

Below is my code for sending the email by Python. It run without error but did not send the email. I check my mailbox it did not receive for this code.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["To"] = 'qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.com'
message["From"] = 'abdullahansari5255@gmail.com'
message["Subject"] = 'muhammad is the best in all over the universs'

title = '<b> Title line here. </b>'
messageText = MIMEText('''muhammad is the best in all over the universs.''','html')
message.attach(messageText)

email = 'abdullahansari5255@gmail.com'
password = '@@@@@@@@@@@@@'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo('Gmail')
server.starttls()
server.login(email,password)
fromaddr = 'abdullahansari5255@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.coms'
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddrs,message.as_string())

server.quit()
```

How to send email by Python?

Comment: The `toaddrs` has `gmail.coms` which doesn't look right.

Comment: `toaddrs  = 'qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.coms'` is this line correct? you have an 's' in the end of 'com'

Comment: Also, make sure the password is an "app password" and not the general password for the Google account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478573/how-to-send-an-email-using-python-after-googles-policy-update-on-not-allowing-j

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: thank you for your help yes sir 's' is extra    ======qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.coms'    com not coms

Answer (score 0):

In your code I found

> toaddrs  = 'qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.coms'

It has an extra 's' at the end of the email address. It should be 'qureshiandsonsinds@gmail.com' without the 's' at the end.

If you are using Gmail, and if your account has two-factor authentication enabled, you should use an "App Password" instead of your regular Gmail password. Generate an App Password specifically for your Python script. You can generate one in your Google Account settings.